# sleep until mysql load the picture

Tags: php, mysql

I've this code:

```
<?php
include 'connectDb.php';

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo file_get_contents('li.gif');
sleep(3);

$id = $_GET['id'];
$row = $conn->query('SELECT picture,img FROM contacts WHERE id=\''.$id.'\' LIMIT 1');
$result = $row->fetch_assoc();
if(!empty($result['picture'])){
    header("Content-type: image/".$result['img']);
    echo($result['picture']);
}
```

What I'm trying to do: show `li.gif` till mysql has loaded the `echo($result['picture'])`.

Is there a way to do this without javascript?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can return just one image. Maybe you could fool the system, by pretending that `li.gif` is the low-res image of a progressively encoded image, or the first frame of an animated gif, but if this is possible at all, you would still at least need some meta information on the image to load, and you'd have to do some complex server side processing to make this happen. I don't think this would be worth the risk. Best solution: don't save the image in MySQL. Bad idea anyway.

Comment: You are actually asking to have some client-side behavior with a server-side language, which is impossible. You should use AJAX for that, because otherwise the webpage (and the `li.gif`) won't load until php and MySQL are done.

Comment: @burflip : Can you this with php only?

Comment: @arijanit-nitti-salihu as said before, nope. You may use Javascript/AJAX or some client-side technology.